# Error deploying to org: "Cannot read property 'success' of undefined"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, error, vs-code

When Deploying anything from VSCode I get the same error everytime. I have created a new project in VSCode using SFDX.

I am able to authorize and retrieve from org, but anytime I deploy I get the same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

when running from VS Code context menu

or

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

when running from CLI

Notes:

- this happens regardless of if it is from vs code context menu or the CLI
- this is in brand new apex classes that have been generated and nothing added and also ones with actual code (meaning its not code errors)
- I have tried: creating a new project, reinstalling java, reinstalling the extension pack. All had the same result.

EDIT:
Issue ended up being that I was connecting to a Production Environment instead of a dev sandbox! You can't directly deploy to Proe, so I just had to swap the org. Thanks for the help all!

Comment: Best way to go about getting to the bottom of this is to open an issue in https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the CLI? "sfdx update" should get you the latest version...Also try running this command from your project's root folder... where the sfdx-project.json file is located.

Answer (score 7):

Just had the same error and I found the root cause: when Apex class .cls and .cls-meta.xml file names do not match, CLI push will fail with that error.

I've logged a bug here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/674

**Update:**

> This is now fixed with CLI version 7.76.1 and salesforcedx plugin version 50.1.1

Comment: @WesC did that solve your question? If yes, can you mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in the latest release
CLI version 7.76.1
salesforcedx plugin version 50.1.1

Run this below command:

**sfdx update**

**sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now in VS while trying to deploy. It also popped up in a CI pipeline that failed the other day.
I did ran 'sfdx update' as Rodrigo indicated, this unfortunately *did not work.*

What fixed it for me was I [re] Authorized an Org to my sandbox environment. Once the authorization was successful, the deployment worked and I no longer received the

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

I hope that works for you as well. The error message lacks any meaning to me. Perhaps it has to do with the token expiring or Username/Credentials may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Some devs mention that updating the Salesforce CLI solves it:

```
sfdx update
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this all day.  I finally got it working.  I recreated the project from scratch, but when I did I chose the standard project template.  Then it started working.

In the past all my projects have worked fine, never had any trouble.  It was just the new project I created today that kept failing time after time.  Its the only one I ever created using the blank template in VS code, all the other I have chosen standard in the past.

I hope this helps.

Hugh

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed when this happened to me was that I had committed my new Apex class but I **hadn't** committed my `.cls-meta.xml` file so when I switched branches and pushed to my class to our full sandbox, I got that same error.

To remedy this, I just went to my other branch and cloned that `.cls-meta.xml` file to my new branch and THEN pushed my Apex class (and its corresponding `xml` file) into our org.

Hopefully that works for your situation too!

Answer (score 0):

1- Uninstall Salesforce CLI

2- Go to windows explorer and use this path "%LOCALAPPDATA%\sfdx"

3- Delete all the files from there

4- Reinstall Salesforce CLI

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and I found that I mistakenly delete the apex class but its meta data file was present...So either remove the metadata apex file or include both files.

Hope it will help!!